# Defining a hash value using another hash value.

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

Is there a way to do the following while using only one data structure?

```
my %hash = (
  "key1" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2",
  "key3" => $hash{key1},
);
```

So basically, I want to set a hash's key value to another key value. I've tried the above syntax but get the following warning:

```
Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name at ...
```

I'm assuming this is because I'm trying to reference the hash before it's actually been created.

Comment: The answer lies in the error message. No, you can't.

Comment: Do you want $hash{key1} and $hash{key3} to be the same value, i.e. changes to $hash{key1} also visible in $hash{key3} ?

Comment: Not sure why you would need to reference another key value in the same declaration since you already know the value (i.e. `"value1"`). If you don't want to retype `"value1"`, make it a variable before declaring `%hash`.

Comment: @MisterEd Because setting variables related to the hash, outside of it, will make it harder to maintain as there would be many. This needs to be a self contained hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make your own function:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub make_hash (@) { 
    my %h;
    my @unresolved;
    while ( @_ ) {
        my ( $key, $value ) = splice( @_, 0, 2 );
        next unless defined $value;
        if (   not ref( $value ) 
           and my ( $ref ) = $value =~ /^ref:\s*(.*\S)\s*$/ 
           ) {
            if ( defined( my $v = $h{ $ref } )) {
                $h{ $key } = $v;
            }
            else {
                push @unresolved, [ $key, $ref ];
            }
        }
        else {
            $value =~ s/^lit://;
            $h{ $key } = $value;
        }
    }
    $h{ $_->[0] } = $h{ $_->[1] } foreach grep { exists $h{ $_->[0] }; } @unresolved;
    return wantarray ? %h : \%h;
}
```

To demonstrate some of the power:

```
my %hash 
    = make_hash(
      'key1' => 'value1'
    , 'key2' => 'value2'
    , 'key3' => 'ref:key1'
    , 'key4' => 'lit:ref:key2'
    , 'key5' => 'lit:lit:ref:key3'
    );
```

The `lit:` prefix covers the case of "What if I *really* wanted to pass a value that is a non-reference as `'ref:so-and-so'`? It also is recursive in answering, "What if I direly need to make a value 'lit:xzy'.

I've done this and I've also blessed a reference to a passed piece of data to a `Lit` class or something along those lines.

```
sub Ref ($) { bless \shift, 'Ref' }
```

And then in the `make_hash` routine you'd just check for `ref( $value ) eq 'Ref'`. And specify it like the following:

```
my %hash 
    = make_hash(
      'key1' => 'value1'
    , 'key2' => 'value2'
    , 'key3' => Ref 'key1'
    );
```

There are many ways to make Perl act like you wish it did.

Comment: This is mostly along the lines of what I am trying to do. But what is a Lit class? Also, if I try your bottom "ref" example I get the following error referring to the "sub Ref":
`Modification of a read-only value attempted`

Comment: @SteveDickinson, why should you need to modify it? It's a key. you just dereference it to get the hashed value. I don't have a problem in Perl 5.14 as long as I stick to referencing it.

Comment: I wouldn't need to modify it. I was simply stating how the "sub Ref" posted above was behaving. The following corrected sub works for me:  
`sub Ref ($) { my $value = shift; bless \$value, 'Ref' }`
  
In addition, I added the following code to the make_hash sub to complete it:  
`...
    } else {
        $value =~ s/^lit://;
        if (ref($value) eq 'Ref') {
            $h{ $key } = $h{$$value};
        } else {
            $h{ $key } = $value;
        }
    }`
  
Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: @SteveDickinson, You're welcome. I have so many options for assembling hashes these days that for the most part I use a function *like* this, but can pass a variety of functions like `-stack_duplicate_keys` to store different values in a "bucket" under a single key. And my version of `Ref` can get to deep levels generally with a `'.'` as delimiter, so like `Ref 'key_1.key_2.3.key_4'` (with the solo '3' being an index into an array.)

Answer (score 9):

This is because, at the moment of using `$hash{key1}`, the symbol "hash" was not yet added to the symbol table. Your package doesn't yet know what `%hash` is, because it won't be added to the symbol table until AFTER the closing ")" is parsed - yet it will encounter the symbol 1 line earlier.

You need to pre-declare %hash in advance:

```
my %hash;

%hash = (
  "key1" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2",
  "key3" => $hash{key1},
);
```

However, while the above will compile, **it will NOT work as expected**, since nothing has been assigned to `%hash` yet when `$hash{key1}` is evaluated. You need to assign it first, as a separate statement:

```
my %hash;

%hash = (
  "key1" => "value1",
  "key2" => "value2",
);

%hash = %hash, (
  "key3" => $hash{key1},
); # Or simply $hash{key3} = $hash{key1};
```

Please note that the above **merely copies the value from `key1` into `key3`, once**. They are in no way linked/associated after that. If you want to alias `key1` and `key3` (e.g. have them **point** to the same value, instead of contain a copy of the value), this is possible but not nearly as trivial. You need to make it into a tied hash and write custom tie handlers to get it right, or have each key's value be a **reference**.

Comment: That gets rid of the warning, however if you were to dump the data it would appear as so:
    ("key2", "value2", "key1", "value1", "key3", undef)

Comment: @SteveDickinson - which of the 2 versions - the one that I said won't work as expected or the one showing how to fix?

Comment: Was there a down vote? I could only see the top solution (which gave the undef) when I replied. The later answer does set the value but I was hoping to set the entire contents of the hash at once.

Comment: @DVK => you can use `Hash::Util::hv_store` to have multiple keys point to the same memory without any ties or explicit references.

Comment: @EricStrom - True, that. But see my comment to your answer

Comment: `"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", "key3" => $hash{key1}` is the assignment's operand, so it's necessarily evaluated before the assignment is evaluated. I removed incorrect implications about impossible behaviour from your post.

Comment: @ikegami - I was 99% sure but not able to open an xterm to check, thus equivocated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want $hash{key1} to be an alias of $hash{key3}, then this can be accomplished easily using [Data::Alias](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Alias).

```
use Data::Alias;

my %hash = (
    key1 => 'value1',
    key2 => 'value2'
);

alias $hash{key3} = $hash{key1};
```

$hash{key1} and $hash{key3} will now refer to a single value, and updates to one will be visible in the other.

Comment: +1 for nice non-source-filter module. Beats tie::hash that I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the core module `Hash::Util` to access the low level `hv_store` routine which can alias values of the hash together.  It isn't quite as clean looking as using `Data::Alias` but it is already installed.

```
use Hash::Util 'hv_store';

my %hash = (
  key1 => "value1",
  key2 => "value2",
);

hv_store %hash, key3 => $hash{key1};

say "$_: $hash{$_}" for sort keys %hash;
# key1: value1
# key2: value2
# key3: value1

$hash{key1} = 'new value';

say "$_: $hash{$_}" for sort keys %hash;
# key1: new value
# key2: value2
# key3: new value
```

if you dont want the aliasing to persist past the initial assignment, then you can just write the line:

```
$hash{key3} = $hash{key1}
```

after your initial declaration and skip using `hv_store`.

Comment: +1 for excellent technical point. Virtual -1 because if you have to do that, you better have a **really** good reason to not redesign your datastructure to be cleaner.

Comment: @DVK => I fully agree that this usage of `hv_store` should be kept away from most sane data-structures, but there are some uses.  It came in handy when I was writing https://metacpan.org/module/Hash::Abbrev for example.

Answer (score 1):

`%hash` doesn't contain anything when creating the list of values to assign to the hash, since you haven't assigned the list to the hash yet.

In fact, `%hash` doesn't exist when creating the list of values to assign to the hash since assignments evaluate their RHS before their LHS. That's why you're getting a strict error.

Some solutions you might like:

```
my %hash = (
  key1 => "value1",
  key2 => "value2",
  key3 => "value1",
);


my $value1 = "value1";
my %hash = (
  key1 => $value1,
  key2 => "value2",
  key3 => $value1,
);


my %hash = (
  ( map { $_ => "value1" } qw( key1 key3 ) ),
  key2 => "value2",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could say

```
my %h; 
my $i = 0;
while (
    my ( $k, $v ) = ( 
        key1 => '"value1"',
        key2 => '"value2"',
        key3 => '$h{key1}',
    )[ $i, $i + 1 ] 
  )
{
    $h{$k} = eval $v; 
    $i += 2;
}
```

as long as any keys referred to appear in the list before they are referenced.